# Can't send Tokbox "signals" on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, tokbox

I can send use Tokbox to send "signals", i.e., text messages, on Chrome v36 but not Firefox v32.

Unfortunately Tokbox's JS library TB.min.js is minified so I can't easily figure out the problem. Here's the errors I'm seeing:

```
no element found ClientEvent:1

TypeError: c is undefined TB.min.js:331
```

Line 331 of TB.min.js:

```
c.updateStream(a,b,d)}.bind(this),destroyStream:function(a){c.destroyStream(a)}.bind(this)};this.signal=function(a,b){c.signal(a,b)};
```

Comment: How about you ask the [Tokbox support about it](http://tokbox.com/support/)? SO cannot be expected to debug problems lacking source code. At the very least, you should provide *your* code that makes use of the library.

Comment: Tokbox support doesn't respond. The code I'm using is simply their demo 'session.on("signal"' code but I'm not sure where the errors are arising because my code isn't logging any console errors. The only problems I see (as reported above) are in their code.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested OpenTokRTC chat (built 100% with OpenTok) on firefox and chrome, they seem to be working
[image]

Here's the sample code of how OpenTokRTC is using signaling for chat: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC/blob/master/public/js/room.js#L297

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of TB.min.js?

Comment: Also at the least the demo code I refer to should be tested. It's not ideal where some demos work and others do not. Still thanks @songz for helping out here.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include link to OpenTokRTC - https://opentokrtc.com/ I used ffox version 34 and ffox 31. The opentok version url: https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.js

Comment: i'm referring to this code from the docs: https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/signaling/js. I believe the `session.on("signal", function(event) {` part doesn't work on Firefox but I can't tell because TB.min.js is minified and I'm only getting the errors mentioned above.